# Why is the singular of "year" used in phrases like "72-year-old" and "20-year jail sentence"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pluralization rule for “five-year-old children”, “20 pound note”, “10 mile run”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/pluralization-rule-for-five-year-old-children-20-pound-note-10-mile-run)

> 72-year-old Giselle Gilbert was taken to hospital.
>   He was given a 20-year jail sentence.

Why is the singular of *year* used in these sentences?

Comment: It's like "32-bit computer."

Answer (score 3):

**##-year-old**, hyphenated is used as a pre-modifier (before the noun) while **is ## years old** is a post modifier.

*The man is 21 years old.*

*a 21-year-old man*

We could also use the singular hyphenated version in place of the noun:

*My sister has a 10-year-old* meaning that she has a child of 10.

That should clear up the usage for those who seemed unsure. Unfortunately, I am not quite sure of the reason for the two forms - I will look into it, though.

Hope that helps.