# Difference between "ten years old" and "ten-year-olds"

Tags: vocabulary

> They are all 10 years old.
>
> They are all ten-year-olds

What is the difference between these?

And, what is the reason why we must add *s* to the following?"

> They are all ten-year-olds

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pluralization rule for "five-year-old children", "20 pound note", "10 mile run"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/). Also [“40-50 years old” vs. “40-50 year olds” when referring to a group](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88205/), [Ways to write “2000 year old”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69742/), [Why is the singular of “year” used in phrases like “72-year-old”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19663/), etc., etc., etc., etc., ...

Comment: The first two Google hits for "ten-year-old" show the adjectival and nounal usages respectively. And there are previous posts on hyphenated pre-modifiers and their unhyphenated predicative counterparts.

Answer (score -1):

In "The are all 10 year old", '10 year old' is used to describe 'they'. In "They are all 10-year-olds", '10-year-olds' is a noun. The first is like saying 'He is a boy' and the second is like saying 'he is brainy'.

Comment: _They are all 10 year old_ is not grammatical (in most varieties of English). _Ten year old_ may be used as an adjective, but only attributively ("a ten year old boy"). And your last sentence is back to front: _ten years old_ is an adjectival phrase like _brainy_, while _ten year olds_ is a noun phrase like _a boy_.