# Are monetary values plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, money

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Are units in English singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/are-units-in-english-singular-or-plural)

I want to say:

> Those sixty dollars are gone
>
> That sixty dollars is gone

The reason I ask is because I was originally typing:

> Those $60 are gone

But that looks funny to me. Which is more correct?

Comment: Also see [Pluralization rule is different when we say 10 pound note and 10 pounds?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24134) and  [Plural words / singular modifiers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70156)

Comment: I would suggest that a monetary amount written numerically with a currency symbol behaves grammatically as would a single bank note of that amount.  By contrast, something written out as "sixty dollars" may either be function grammatically as a single sixty-dollar note, or as sixty individual dollars.

Comment: Though this was marked as duplicate, I feel that preferred question really could not answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

Plural if you're thinking of the $60 as 60 individual dollars, singular if you're thinking of the sum of money as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

> Those sixty dollars are gone
>
> That sixty dollars is gone

I believe that both *those* and *that* work when the amount is spelled out, but just as you've written them as PeterShor and Barrie have said with plural and singular verb agreement.

***Those** sixty dollars **were** supposed to be my ticket out of this town, and now **they're** sailing away on a strong southern breeze*.

***That** sixty dollars **was** supposed to be my ticket out of this town, and now **it's** sailing away on a strong southern breeze*.

> Those $60 are gone

When the amount is presented as currency, I believe *[that](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/46849564/ns/business-world_business/t/shell-iran-about-b-were-working-it/#.T9yr6sXenX4)* is the better [choice](http://nymag.com/daily/intel/2011/11/facebook-can-practically-taste-10-billion-ipo.html).

Comment: @PeterShor ah yes; that distinction didn't catch my attention.  :x

Comment: I think if you say *those* you have to use plural, and if you say *that*, you have to use singular.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you thing "Those $60 are gone" looks funny because the symbol "$" substitutes the word "dollars", and the symbol doesn't require a plural, but the expression is correct.
I'd say that a possible use of the singular version could be when talking about some amount of money that could be a single dollar bill, for example, $10.
Then, you could say "That $10 is gone".