# "Forty foot" or "forty feet"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number, measuring-units

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pluralization rule for “five-year-old children”, “20 pound note”, “10 mile run”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/pluralization-rule-for-five-year-old-children-20-pound-note-10-mile-run)

Is it correct to say

> "This is a forty foot drop"

or

> "That is a [forty foot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/40-foot_telescope) telescope"

Shouldn't it be "forty feet"?

And what if it is

> "This is a thirty nine foot drop"

instead?

Are both correct? Does it depend on the context? How does it work?

Comment: Does it depends on the region? I heard Bear Grylls ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_Grylls ) say `40 foot drop`, he was born in UK.

Comment: Are there any multi-linguists among us who can say whether this counter-intuitive 'singularisation' occurs in other languages?

Comment: You can read here all about the _[Forty Foot Drain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forty_Foot_Drain)_

Comment: @FumbleFingers: For the length scale you would say (singular) "Vierzig Fuß"  in German instead of "Vierzig Füße" (plural), too, except usually the metric system is used. Also 7 Euro and not 7 Euros is used (except when there are 7 single Euro-*coins*). But a "5 Jahre altes Kind" contains "Jahre" (years), not "Jahr" (year), and a "10 Meilen Lauf" uses "Meilen" (miles) instead of "Meile" (mile).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *forty-foot drop* is correct.

Compare this:

> 1) He's a 10-year old.
>
> 2) He's 10 years old.

In the first example, *a 10-year old* stands as a noun (notice the article preceding it).
In the second example, it's not a noun, therefore no article.

Therefore:

> 1) It's a 40-foot drop.
>
> 2) This drop is 40 feet in height.

Comment: William Safire has a great article on this, published in "What's the Good Word." He notes that in constructions like "toothbrush," adjectival modifiers are normally singular.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks. And thanks @The Raven for this info, its very nice to know it.

Comment: would "This is a forty foot drop" and "This is a forty foot deep drop" change this?