# Height and Weight — How to write them when abbreviations are not used

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, measuring-units

Height and Weight — How to write them when abbreviations are not used.

He was a *6-foot 5-inch man*.

(Not: 6-foot-5-inch man, with three hyphens.)

She gave birth to a *7-pound 11-ounce baby*.

(Not: 7-pound-11-ounce baby, with three hyphens.)

And, it should be, I believe:

He is *6 feet 5 inches tall*. (Not: 6 feet, 5 inches tall.)

The baby weighed *7 pounds 11 ounces*. (Not: 7 pounds, 11 ounces.)

Despite variations in punctuation, I believe that we do not separate singular units of measurements like these with commas.

Good to all?

Comment: Don't shoot me, but _1.87 meters_ has advantages :P

Comment: Huh? I don't understand.

Comment: I think it is alright to say 'six foot tall' rather than 'six feet tall'. In the same way we can talk about 20 ton of carrots.

Comment: @whippoorwill: never mind that, it's just that this "problem" is a lot simpler (or doesn't exist) if you use a decimal system. But that is off-topic :)

Comment: Nobody ever says "six-foot-five-inch man". They say "six-foot-five man". (Both with and without hyphens).

Comment: They say it in America. I've heard multiple times.

Comment: So are my examples punctuated correctly?

Comment: You're right; they do say it. You can use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22five+foot+seven+man%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22five+foot+seven+inch+man%22&tbm=bks) to look and see how other people punctuated it. If you're writing for a specific publication, they will have a style guide which may or may not cover this. If not, there's no authority to say which way is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't we pluralize "foot" in measurements?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28457/why-dont-we-pluralize-foot-in-measurements)

Comment: If you use foot and inch notations, it would be 6' 5" tall -- not 6', 5" tall.  So I believe that your "6 foot 5 inches" is correct.

Comment: In running text, do you think this works? The man is 6'5" tall (or simply, 6'5"). For the compound modifier, how about: He is a 6'5" juggernaut.

Comment: Can this work? It sure as heck is concise and understandable.

Comment: I think the spelled-out height reads better if you are writing prose.  The notated format is more technical. I would use it in tables and in text if the number of times I needed to reference heights became awkward and wordy.

Answer (score 4):

Your suggested punctuation system for compound or mixed measurements seems perfectly reasonable—and it finds support in at least one style guide. From *Words Into Type* (1974):

> **Dimensions, weights, and measures.** Commas are unnecessary in the punctuation of phrases denoting dimensions, weights, and measures.
>
> five feet seven inches
>
> 4 lb 3 oz
>
> 5 hr 10 min
>
> His age is 6 years 4 months 12 days.

On the other hand, the house style at the publisher I work for has long required a comma between hours and minutes when reporting timed results of performance tests—such as "4 hours, 39 minutes." The *Chicago Manual of Style*, 15th edition (2003) doesn't directly address the question of how to handle such mixed measurements, but one entry happens to show how the University of Chicago Press deals with them:

> **9.45** *Seconds and dates included.* A variation of the twenty-four-hour system [of expressing time] shows hours, minutes, and seconds separated by colons; it also shows fraction of a second following a period. This format may be preceded by an ISO-style date [cross reference omitted].
>
> 09:27:08.6 = 27 minutes, 8.6 seconds after 9:00 a.m.
>
> 1999-05-10-16:09:41.3 = May 5, 1999, at 9 minutes, 41.3 seconds after 4:00 p.m.

In both of these instances, Chicago is centrally concerned with translating the "twenty-four-hour system" variant examples (first without and then with a preceding ISO-style date) from numerals into words; but in doing so, it consistently separates the minute term from the second term with a comma, contrary to the *Words Into Type* recommendation.

Either the *Words Into Type* approach or the Chicago approach, if consistently used, should achieve the primary goal of any such system of punctuation, which is to convey the relevant measurements clearly while posing a negligible distraction to readers.

Comment: The Chicago Manual of Style is intended I think for things like newspapers where typographical space has historically been at a premium.  I think that when discussing durations, "three hours and fifteen minutes" often reads better than "3 hours, 15 minutes"; the latter takes less typographical space, however.  With regard to other dimensions, I would suggest that one should abbreviate units when using numerals, and write them out when using words; the numeral form should be favored except when forming a multi-word adjective phrase (e.g. a six-foot-four gentleman).