# "In second" or "in seconds" when talking about time

Tags: grammatical-number, time

When talking about time as a unit, which one is correct, *in second* or *in seconds*?

For example:

> How long does it take to complete the task in second?

or

> How long does it take to complete the task in seconds?

Comment: I think this is general reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct form is *in seconds*:

> Please specify the time in seconds (in minutes, in days, in years, etc).

Comment: I agree, however I think a more interesting question is whether or not to pluralise the units when stating a figure. i.e. 23 Metres or 23 Metre.

Comment: @Urbycoz: The length of the cloth is 23 *meters*. Why would it be 23 meter?

Comment: @Armen. It would be a 23 meter race not a 23 meters race.

Comment: @artfullyContrived: Indeed, because in this case it acts like an adjective, not a noun. A 12 year old boy is playing in the street. The boy that's playing in the street is 12 yearS old.

Comment: @Armen. I agree that's what people tend to say in practice, but it's debatable. The argument is that scientifically "metre" is only there to denote the units. It should never be pluralised. You would always write 23m, never 23ms.

Comment: @Urbycoz: I agree that you never write 23ms for 23 meters. But I also maintain that you never pronounce 23m as 23 meter.

Comment: @art there's a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/pluralization-rule-for-five-year-old-children-20-pound-note-10-mile-run) for that. It's completely unrelated to the question at hand. Let's stay on-topic. Same goes for Urbycoz and others. If you have a different question, use the "Ask Question" link. Don't bury it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use the plural, "seconds".

In general, when you do not know whether the number of something is one or more than one, you use the plural.

Like, "How many people attended the meeting?", NOT "How many person attended the meeting?"

Even if the number is most likely one: "Polygamy is illegal here, but the number of wives Bob has is unknown." NOT "number of wife".