# Should "forty-year" in this context be hyphenated?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, orthography, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pluralization rule for “five-year-old children”, “20 pound note”, “10 mile run”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/pluralization-rule-for-five-year-old-children-20-pound-note-10-mile-run)

> Mr. Willow’s more than forty-year experience in the industry persuaded me to apply.

Or is the following a better way of saying it?

> Mr. Willow's more than forty years of experience in the industry persuaded me to apply.

Are they both correct, or should the hyphen in the first example be removed?

Comment: What research have you done in this? Or is this just a proofreading question?

Answer (score 2):

The first is fine. From the [Guardian style guide](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/h) hyphen entry:

> There is no need to use hyphens with most
>   compound adjectives, where the meaning is
>   clear and unambiguous without: civil rights movement, financial services sector, work
>   inspection powers, etc. Hyphens should,
>   however, be used to form short compound
>   adjectives, eg two-tonne vessel, three-year deal,
>   19th-century artist. Also use hyphens where not
>   using one would be ambiguous, eg to distinguish "black-cab drivers come under
>   attack" from "black cab-drivers come under
>   attack". A missing hyphen in a review of
>   Chekhov's Three Sisters led us to refer to "the
>   servant abusing Natasha", rather than "the
>   servant-abusing Natasha".

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem it's not where you think it is.

You're actually completely missing a word in the first sentence. You're comparing "more than", but more than that what?

> Mr. Willows's more than forty-year **long** experience ...

That would be the correct version.

The second sentence is correct and needs no changes.

Comment: *Long* isn't *needed*; indeed is wrong as shown.  One might write “Mr. Willow's  forty-year-long experience ...”, but better, “Mr. Willow's  forty-year experience ...”.  If the odious *more than* has to be there, it probably should be hyphenated: “Mr. Willow's  more-than-forty-year experience ...”