# "40-50 years old" vs. "40-50 year olds" when referring to a group

Tags: grammatical-number, hyphenation, dashes

In formal research, which is more correct, and why:

- the group of **40-50 years old**
  OR
- the group of **40-50 year olds**

In any case the phrase in bold is to be treated as a noun only, as in:

> The middle group of executives, ie. *40-50 years old* is well
>   balanced....

Without a range, the hyphenation rules I am used to would suggest "15-year olds" for instance.  However "the **15-25-year olds** ..." doesn't present well, does it?

There are related questions here, but none that seem to exactly address this topic. Eg.

[Pluralization rule for "five-year-old children", "20 pound note", "10 mile run"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/pluralization-rule-for-five-year-old-children-20-pound-note-10-mile-run)

The main difference perhaps is that I need to use ranges, which already use a hyphen.

Comment: "The group of 40-50 year olds" is the noun phrase. The other is not. Why did you have a doubt? In the example sentence, the phrase serves as a qualifier for the noun *executives* before it, and as such it is also correct, though needs a comma after it.

Comment: Incorrectly punctuated, and omit the "**e.g.**", which would normally be the verbosity (in this case) "**i.e.**". Should be: "**The middle group of executives, those 40-50 years old, is well balanced....**"

Comment: You can use "the **15- to 25-year-olds ...**" instead. That looks better.

Comment: For ranges, [en dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) are used, not hyphens.

Comment: @RegDwight: True, but I never use en dashes. I let the publisher format the text. They do it anyway.

Comment: @BillFranke We have met the publisher, and he is us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using it as a compound adjective or noun, as in your example sentence, it should be "40-50-year-olds".

If you are using it as a separate qualifier, as in BillFranke's suggested alternate wording, than it would be "those 40-50 years old".

Confusing, perhaps, but the general rule is that when any sort of counted "thing" is used as an adjective, the object of the count is singular. "40-year-old man", "3-mile run", etc. Making it a range instead of a single number doesn't change that.

But when a number and an object of that number are used "on their own", i.e. not as a compound word, the normal rules of pluralization apply: "those 1 year old", "those 2 years old", etc.

Comment: Thank you; thus ranges shouldn't affect the compound-adjective dashing. One of the things I like about these SEs is that people tend to include references supporting answers, to be sure. I don't have one myself but remember from high school, and based on not letting ranges change things as you imply, that "40-50-year olds" should be correct, allowing a space to separate the adjective from the noun.