# grammar age question

Tags: word-usage

Consider the sentence - "A fifty year old man is walking in the garden."
Shouldn't it be ***'fifty years old'***  or  ***'fifty-year old'*** or something else maybe? Is the original usage correct?

Comment: Also related: [Pluralization rule for “five-year-old children”, “20 pound note”, “10 mile run”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/pluralization-rule-for-five-year-old-children-20-pound-note-10-mile-run), and the many questions linked from there.

Answer (score 1):

In AP style, all ages are written as numerals.  You would only hyphenate the age if it is an adjective.  Therefore, the correct way to write the sentence would be: **A 50-year-old man was walking in the garden.**

Comment: Only British English please.

Comment: Written English has no dialect, because you can't hear it. The important point -- and it's important to **all** English versions, is that only a single-word adjective can precede the noun; all adjectives of more than one word follow the noun. So, if writing English, either _fifty-year-old man_ or _50-year-old man_ is correct. As long as it's only one word, typographically and grammatically.

Comment: It's also possible to use the hyphenated phrase as a noun, not adverting to the individual's gender (or species, though human being is strongly implied unless you've just been talking about, say, Galapagos tortoises): "A fifty-year-old is walking in the garden." And you can reframe the wording to get rid of the hyphens if for some reason you don't like them: "A man, fifty years old, is walking in the garden." But certainly the standard handling of the situation is the one that naish2013 gives.